# IntelliJ Scala REPL not Displaying My Worksheet Code

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, read-eval-print-loop

I am trying to work on a Scala worksheet in IntelliJ 14. When I first open the worksheet, a 0.5 is displayed in the REPL window and when I try to evaluate my worksheet, there is some very brief loading and then the REPL clears and nothing is displayed.

All I have right now is `val number = 5`.

The IntelliJ plugin for Scala I have installed is Version `1.5.2`

Does anyone have any tips or troubleshooting information that can help me get to the bottom of this issue?

Comment: In the settings for the Scala language, are the following checked: "Run worksheet in the compiler process", "Run worksheet in the interactive mode"

Comment: Where do I go to check if these are checked?  Sorry, not very familiar with navigating IntelliJ

EDIT: Nevermind found it.  Yes, both are checked.

Comment: You might try unchecking the compile process one - if you have errors in your general project, I *believe* it won't compile the worksheet then.

Comment: I unchecked it, but still having this issue where my REPL is not displaying anything.  Hmm.

Comment: @Imcphers Did you resolve this issue? I have the same problem. It might  have something to do with the error: `scala: Cannot connect to compile server at localhost/127.0.0.1:3200` , but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Lukasz Oh geez, it's been a long time since I've looked at this!  I think it ended up working, but I don't remember how I fixed it now. :S  I haven't been doing much with worksheets lately or a REPL window.